# I'm running a Tor Relay on my Raspberry Pi, is it safe to use the Raspberry Pi as a proxy for all the machines on the LAN?

Tags: configuration

Recently I've been reading lots of comments stating it's not safe to use your own Tor Relay as a proxy into the Tor Network, but typically none of these conversations have any evidence to substantiate their claims.  I'd be willing to write it off as FUD, but for something as important as Tor I wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something unnecessarily stupid!

So, my setup is really simple;  I have a [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) which is running the Tor Relay and has been doing for the past three or four months without any significant problems.

After some reading, I set the following options in my `torrc` file which I believe restrict access to the proxy only machines on my local network.  Is that right?

```
## Entry policies to allow/deny SOCKS requests based on IP address.
## First entry that matches wins. If no SocksPolicy is set, we accept
## all (and only) requests that reach a SocksPort. Untrusted users who
## can access your SocksPort may be able to learn about the connections
## you make.
SocksListenAddress 192.168.0.34
SocksPolicy accept 192.168.0.0/16
SocksPolicy reject *
```

So for every device or application on my LAN that needs access to the Tor Network, I just point them all to the SOCKS5 Proxy running on the Raspberry Pi. The Raspberry Pi's IP address is 192.168.0.34, so I point every device to: 192.168.0.34:9050.

So, are there any major security implications that could lower my anonymity using my setup?

Comment: Read this thread about safety of RPi: http://marc.info/?l=openbsd-misc&m=132794042820760&w=2 In short: > > > i'm hoping the raspberrypi will eventually be supported on openbsd
> > > (if the hardware proves to be stable, $35 sounds GREAT) but i don't
> > > have the skills to go there myself.
> > > > Wow. Dream on. It is a mess of firmware. You know nothing of our
> > history?

Answer (score 1):

The question is the same for any non-TorBrowser application you point to a Tor proxy, locally or on your network.

The problem is, at least for me, that you won't understand each and every detail on what could go wrong and what could leak by doing so. Making sure DNS is resolved over Tor is a good first step but I don't want to know, for example, how Internet Explorer behaves in that case.

Pointing people to Tor Browser wherever possible is probably the safer way.

Answer (score 0):

Just DNS leaks can compromise you now : make sure that no dot-onion DNS resolve will reach your upstream DNS servers